# Labels of the 'ALAssetsLibrary' access request alert view aren't recognized by KIF

Tags: ios, objective-c, integration-testing, alassetslibrary, kif

I'm writing a [KIF test](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) to test the onboarding flow of the iPhone app I'm working on. When asking the `ALAssetsLibrary` for access the usual alert view pops up, but KIF doesn't recognize the accessibility labels of this alert view.

[image: Screenshot]

My test fails when I test for the following:

```
[tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"OK"];
```

This while my Accessibility Inspector in my iOS Simulator clearly states that this is the right label for this view.

I'm wondering if this is because these alert views are outside the sandbox, does anybody know if this is the case and if there might be some work around for testing it with KIF?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that UIAlertViews are shown in an other window, or like you suspect, the alert view is presented from another process which should be unreachable to the apps code. Is there a way to check for views in another UIWindow instance?

**Update**

As noted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kif-framework/iDBomK8kyL8/wLtlh80YrpsJ

> As I understand it touch events are routed by iOS to a UIWindow, which is then responsible for dealing with them as it sees fit. KIF and friends use a technique where touch events are synthetically created and then sent to a UIWindow. Since your app code doesn't have access to the UIWindow which is presenting the alert box, your app has no way to send it a touch event.

Of course you can manually loop through the windows of the UIApplication with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]` or use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`, but I don't think the testing framework supports that.

Comment: Looks like you're right, I found [a discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kif-framework/iDBomK8kyL8/wLtlh80YrpsJ) that supports your suspicion. Care to include this link and a quote in your answer? Then I’ll accept it as THE answer.